# Characterizing functions which satisfy Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

Charecterize all complex valued functions $f$ satisfying below statement:

> Suppose $C$ is a simple closed curve inside a simply connected domain $D$ and for any point $a$ inside $C$,
> $$2i\pi f(a)=\int_C \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,dz$$

Characterizing means finding whether $f$ is analytic inside $C$, or whether it has any singularities inside $C$ , or it is not analytic inside $C $ etc.

I try to prove that $f$ is analytic inside $C$ mimicking the proof of Cauchy integral formula for $f'(a)$ but I get stuck in some steps as we do not even know whether $f$ is continuous. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The existence of the Cauchy integral implies $f$ integrable on curves and then $f$ continuous follows by standard arguments (for $a_n \to a$ express $f(a_n), f(a)$ by integrals on the same circle surrounding them and apply the dominated convergence theorem) and then analyticity follows similarly by expressing the power series at $a$ from the geometric series for $1/(z-a)$

Comment: @Conrad Can you please elaborate on the point $f$ is integrable on curves? Here $C$ is a given simple closed curve inside the domain.

Comment: $f$ is integrable on $C$ if you just fix it and then everything above applies for inside $C$ only - on $C$ you only can say that $f$ has limit ae (non tangentially) and that limit is integrable so for example if $C$ is a circle this means that $f$ is in $H^1$; if you allow $C$ to vary then $f$ is analytic everywhere in the domain; so $f$ can be quite discontinuous on $C$ itself (and arbitrary outside) but Cauchty still holds and $f$ is analytic inside $C$ with limits ae